# TypeError 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I got an error,
TypeError at /ResultJSON/v1/results/
'tuple' object is not callable      .

I wrote a method in views.py,

```
results = OrderedDict([
        ('id',x.id)
        ('name', x.name)
        for x in Post.objects.all()
    ])
```

When I browsed this error,I read the error happen because there is no comma (,).

But I added  commas between ('id',x.id) and  ('name', x.name) and last of  ('name', x.name),I got an error No Python interpreter configured for the project.

So,I cannot understand why this error happen.How can I fix it?

In views.py,I wrote

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from django.http import HttpResponse
from accounts.models import Post


def render_json_response(request, data, status=None):

    json_str = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    callback = request.GET.get('callback')
    if not callback:
        callback = request.POST.get('callback')
    if callback:
        json_str = "%s(%s)" % (callback, json_str)
        response = HttpResponse(json_str, content_type='application/javascript; charset=UTF-8', status=status)
    else:
        response = HttpResponse(json_str, content_type='application/json; charset=UTF-8', status=status)
    return response

def UserResult(request):

    results = OrderedDict([
        ('id',x.id)
        ('name', x.name)
        for x in Post.objects.all()
    ])

    data = OrderedDict([ ('results', results) ])
    return render_json_response(request, data)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? A dictionary can only hold **unique** keys, you can't generate multiple `id` and `name` keys and have that work.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to produce a *list of dictionaries* instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing syntax; you can't put a list comprehension mixed in with some literal elements, and a list comprehension can't produce more than one element per iteration.

Moreover, you can't produce one dictionary (ordered or otherwise) that contains multiple copies of a key.

I suspect you are trying to create multiple dictionaries instead in a list, each one containing the id and name:

```
results = [OrderedDict([('id', x.id), ('name', x.name)])
           for x in Post.objects.all()]
```

It may be more efficient and readable to query the database only for the id and name fields:

```
fields = ('id', 'name')
results = [OrderedDict(zip(fields, x))
           for x in Post.objects.order_by. values_list(*fields)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole ordered dict thing you're trying to do looks a little unnecessary, just create it using the django queryset

```
results = Post.objects.order_by().values_list('id', 'name')  # or values()..
```

Comment: It would be more consistent to use `values()` (returns dictionaries) instead of `values_list` (returns tuples). The above will work, *unless* the ordering of the keys in the response is important, in which case an ordered dict would be required.

Comment: @Alasdair - Yes, I hadn't figured out which would be best for the OP's use case here because its not clear at all what they intend to use this on. (I can't think of anything where a list of ordered dicts would be useful..)

Comment: thx, ur comments.When I wrote ur codes,I got an error,TypeError at /ResultJSON/v1/results/
<QuerySet [(1, None), (2, None), (3, None), (4, None), (5, None), (6, None), (7, None), (8, None), (9, None), (10, None), (11, None), (12, None), (13, None), (14, None), (15, None), (16, None), (17, None), (18, None), (19, None), (20, None), '...(remaining elements truncated)...']> is not JSON serializable

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: @user7523656 - You could reply to [Martijn Pieter's comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137551/typeerror-tuple-object-is-not-callable#comment71441479_42137551)